# Referencing using Misc

Tags: bibtex

Surprisingly I can not find an answer to this question. Where does the author go in the following example:

```
@misc{Chen,
title = {{Chen. H} Basics of Probability Theory},
  howpublished = {\url{http://www.math.ntu.edu.tw/~hchen/teaching/StatInference/notes/lecture2.pdf}},
  note = {Accessed: 2013-15-4}
}
```

The problem that is occurring for me is the in the form I currently have it I am getting alphabetical ordering for web resources but the books are being involved.

Comment: apparently H. Chen is the author, and the rest of the title field is the proper title. Have you considered using an auxiliary software such as [JabRef](http://jabref.sourceforge.net)? I'd also recommend reading this [introduction to bibliographic databases in BibTeX format by Andrew Roberts](http://www.andy-roberts.net/writing/latex/bibliographies).

Comment: No I have not as I rarely use latex. I will check the document to see if it helps me. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Valid fields for `@misc` bibtex entries are author, title, howpublished, month, year, note and key.  Your bibtex entry should look as follows:

```
@misc{Chen,
  author = {Chen, H.},
  title = {Basics of Probability Theory},
  howpublished = {\url{http://www.math.ntu.edu.tw/~hchen/teaching/StatInference/notes/lecture2.pdf}},
  note = {Accessed: 2013-15-4}
}
```

If there is a problem with ordering the entries, you can add a `key` field.  If this field is present, it is used for the alphabetical ordering of entries (but creates no output).